# Implement a socket connection for unity3d and signalr

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, signalr

I am going to implement a socket client for unity3D by C# which connects to signalr . Here is my code:

```
public void StartClient()
{

    try
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("http://www.MYURL.com/signalr/hubs");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        print(e.ToString());
    }
}
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        print("Socket connected to "+client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        //connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

But when I calling StartClient() , it will throw this:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known.
```

on server side every thing is correct and the HTML page which handles signalr, works correctly for browser based clients. I am going to implement  my own client for unity but it is not working..

I now that I should send GET Request something like this:

```
GET /signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chapter3hub%22%7D%5D&_=142051 HTTP/1.1
```

Then I should get ConnectionID and ConnectionToken from the response of above request , and send the Post Reqeust again to authorize user :

```
POST /signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=GaRyosG%2Fu1%2BU%2B9yusdn0lVb&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chapter3hub%22%7D%5D
```

But I don't know how to create a connection between unity3d and signalr which is placed in my own server? should I use sockets or there is a way like long polling ?

Comment: I guess you are not using SignalR's client API implementations because its not supported on Unity3d? Or am I wrong? If so, have you checked https://github.com/jenyayel/SignalR.Client.20

Comment: Yes because unity3D .net framework is 2.0 , I had see this project , but I want to write my own library which makes some simple task ( it's kinda static) !

Comment: ah, so you have a nice reference implementation now :) SignalR is not trivial, its using websockets as sa main transport and falls back onto other things (like long polling and hidden frames) if ws is not avail

Comment: yes I had read the documentation , in my project both server and clients accepts websockets . the  implementation  you mentioned is nice but it is very complicated I think . I need the connection between unity and server be clarified

Comment: so are you going to implement websockets yourself too?

Comment: Suppose there is a blank project in unity3d which wants to connect to a signalr . I don't know how to handle server events , for this issue I think  I use websockets or sockets . for this achievement , maybe implementation in unity is necessary !

Answer (score 1):

SignalR 2.x is HTTP based. From your code it's hard to tell what port you used but the issue may be that you were not using port 80. Then you try to use webSocket transport but to do that you need to use a webSocket client really (unless you want also to implement webSocket protocol on your own which is not trivial).
If you really want to write the SignalR client here are my pointers:

- [Here](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) is a description of the SignalR protocol I wrote some time ago
- SignalR is open source and you can get some ideas from the code: https://github.com/Signalr/SignalR
- the most basic but complete client that only supports webSockets protocol is this https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp
- Because SignalR 2.x is HTTP based you want to use the HttpClient/WebClient and not Sockets

Comment: If I use HTTP from unity3D , it is simple,very simple . but how can implement OnMessage or OnClose methods? How can I handle callbacks of server sent data ? and unfortunately your first link : I cannot open it

Comment: Not sure why you can't open the link - "works on my machine". Try copying it from here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/
The OnMessage is a result of transport receiving data so it is on top of HTTP. The OnClose is a result of stopping the client or client getting an error and not being able to reconnect. SignalR C# client itself is built on top of HTTP Client and WebSocket client for webSocket transport - check the code to get the idea.

Comment: You mean , I should call OnMessage on my client by checking the response body ? so if yes how often should I do this , its kind of request , I can done it without signalr , I want to do this without any request,please inform me with some code ,  also I am reading your link , by the way what is tid in post parameterr ? is it transport id?  how can set that?

Comment: OnMessage will be called depending on the transport - for webSockets it corresponds to ReceiveAsync, for serverSentEvents it is when a new "data" frame is received for long polling it is related to a finished poll request. I already provided two reference implementations (actually 3 because the SignalR repo contains not only C# but also javascript client) in my response.

Comment: when I send connect request with connectionToken and data , server response is : The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format. , WHY?